# Is there a program on which to make a quiz that runs Python code? I.e. The person enters code, then the quiz runs it on a kernel

Tags: python

Every single query of this sort I could find simply involved making some kind of Multiple Choice Quiz using Python that took in values like "a" or "b" as input.

What I'm thinking involves the user actually having to write proper python code and running it in a kernel, while it gets checked against the correct answers.

For instance the user might be asked to use python code to solve a problem, then assign the final answer to the variable "ans".

The quiz program would then check whether the "ans" value was correct based on what the value the test-setter determined it should be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this can help https://pypi.org/project/quizzer/ but you have to write code by your self at the end. you can simply use it to make coding easier